# ovs internal port / veth pairs bandwidth limitation

Tags: port, openstack, switching

I have been doing some experiments on ovs these days. I have 2 physical machines with openstack running on it, and GRE tunnel is configured. I add 2 internal ports on br-int (integration bridge) of each machine and assign them to different namespace(ns1, ns2, ns3, ns4) and ip from same subnet(172.16.0.200,172.16.0.201,172.16.0.202,172.16.0.203). After configuration is done, VM(in same subnet)<-> virtual ports , virtual port <->virtual port on same/different nodes are all reachable(Use ping to test). However, weird thing shows up: I have used iperf to test the bandwidth, testing result shows as following:

1. Physical node<-> Physical node: 1GB/s
2. VM<->VM on same machine: 10GB/s
3. VM<->VM on different machines: 1GB/s
4. VM<->Virtual port same machine: 10GB/s
5. VM<->Virtual port different machines: 1GB/s
6. Virtual port<->Virtual port same machine: 16GB/s
7. Virtual port<->Virtual port different machines: **100~200kb/s (WEIRD!)**

I have tried replace internal port with veth pairs, same behavior shows up.
As I expect, the veth pair should behave similar to a VM because they both have separate namespace , and openstack VM uses same way (Veth pairs) to connect to br-int. But the experiment shows that the VM(node1) -> Virtual port(node2) has 1GB/s bandwidth but Virtual port(node1) -> Virtual port(node2) only has 100kb/s ? Anybody has any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When using GRE (or VXLAN, or other overlay network), you need to make sure that the MTU inside your virtual machines is *smaller* than the MTU of your physical interfaces.  The GRE/VXLAN/etc header adds bytes to outgoing packets, which means that an MTU sized packet coming from a virtual machine will end up larger than the MTU of your host interfaces, causing fragmentation and poor performance.

This is documented, for example, [here](http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/neutron-network-node.html):

> Tunneling protocols such as GRE include additional packet headers that
>   increase overhead and decrease space available for the payload or user
>   data. Without knowledge of the virtual network infrastructure,
>   instances attempt to send packets using the default Ethernet maximum
>   transmission unit (MTU) of 1500 bytes. Internet protocol (IP) networks
>   contain the path MTU discovery (PMTUD) mechanism to detect end-to-end
>   MTU and adjust packet size accordingly. However, some operating
>   systems and networks block or otherwise lack support for PMTUD causing
>   performance degradation or connectivity failure.
>
> Ideally, you can prevent these problems by enabling jumbo frames on
>   the physical network that contains your tenant virtual networks. Jumbo
>   frames support MTUs up to approximately 9000 bytes which negates the
>   impact of GRE overhead on virtual networks. However, many network
>   devices lack support for jumbo frames and OpenStack administrators
>   often lack control over network infrastructure. Given the latter
>   complications, you can also prevent MTU problems by reducing the
>   instance MTU to account for GRE overhead. Determining the proper MTU
>   value often takes experimentation, but 1454 bytes works in most
>   environments. You can configure the DHCP server that assigns IP
>   addresses to your instances to also adjust the MTU.

Comment: Hey it works! It is exactly because of MTU. After modification, the bandwidth between virtual ports on different nodes raised to 900+MB. Thanks @larsks

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, consider clicking on the checkbox to the left of the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie here so don't have enough reputation to vote... But I believe new comer will vote become it is a truly helpful answer. Thank you so much